# In Android, how can I set the order of children in a FrameLayout as they're added?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout that will hold a set of ImageViews. I'm using FrameLayout because I actually want them to overlap. However, as I add items to the Layout I don't want them to just stack. I actually need to order them.

The image are pulled form storage and I have their correct order stored in my database so:

```
Image1 - layerNumber: 3
Image2 - layerNumber: 12
Image3 - layerNumber: 1
Image4 - layerNumber: 34
Image5 - layerNumber: 6
Image6 - layerNumber: 30
```

When I place them in the FrameLayout I'll need to them to in the Layout in the layerNumber order. Also, I'll be adding one or more at a time as I use the app. I may tab something that adds "Image50 - layerNumber: 10".

What I was hoping to do was use something like ImageView.setChildOrder(x) or something like that. Is there any way of doing this?

----- edit -----
per @fifarunnerr I did something like this:

```
productLayers.addView(productIV, Integer.parseInt(productItem.get(1)));
```

`productItem.get(1)` is just the layerNumber. For this example it's on layer 23.

I get the error: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=23 count=3`

I understand the error: I'm trying to place a view in a layout that has 3 "spots" at the 23rd spot. As you can see in my numbers from earlier, the layerNumber won't always be in a 1..2..3..4... pattern.

Comment: you simply want to show each image overlapped like layer?

Comment: yes, but their layerNumber is important as some items need to be behind others.

Answer (score 6):

The z-order of children in the FrameLayout depends on the order in which the items are added, according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685019/1571490).

So you could sort the layerNumber, and then add the childrens in the correct order, or you could use the [addView(view, index)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29) method.

Comment: Looks like `adView(view,index)` might do it. If it does I'll check this as the answer.

Comment: getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=23 count=3` error. I'm trying to set the index of 23 (it's on the 23rd layer) but there are only 3 layers.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the way you want to do it, but you could simply declare your `ImageView`s wrapped into Relative/LinearLayouts, and setting each Layout an id, you could simply call `relativeLayout1.bringToFront()` on it.